# How to call a function of an activity trying to intent in another activity from mainactivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I want to make a Android java package to intent to an activity
But whenever i trying to intent it is giving me nullpointerexception
When I run it
There is a newweb.java class in which there is this function

```
Public Void openweb(Context con,String url){
    Intent i=new Intent(con,myweb.class);
i.putStringExtra("webcode",url);
startactivity(i);

   }
```

myweb is an activity

In Mainactivity

```
    newweb web=new newweb();
Web.openweb(Mainactivity.this,url);
```

But error occurred
nullpointerexception in newweb during intent

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit your question. Post the relevant code and the exception message with stacktrace. This will help us pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Try the answers to [what is a nullpointer exception and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it#:~:text=The%20NullPointerException%20(NPE)%20occurs%20when,that%20does%20not%20actually%20exist.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit unclear but i guess youre trying to load a url using a webview on button click

1. **In your Activity A**

```
public void openWeb(String url){
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("webUrl",url);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

2.**In your Activity B**

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String url=intent.getStringExtra("webUrl");
webView.loadUrl(url);
```